# Como posso Incorporar textos e retornar da última até a primeira imagem do slideshow?

Tags: jquery, css, slider, eventos-do-mouse, z-index

Tenho 9 imagens e estão para serem mostradas em um *slide*, com botão `mousein`, `mouseout`, `Loading`, `Z-index`. Até aí tudo bem, o CSS tá certinho.

Nos *slideshows* não tenho conseguido colocar meus textos para acompanhar as fotos  que mostro. Eu não sei se coloco *tags* intercalando *ids* de fotos ou após estas *ids*, ou se o erro sobre isso está no `#texto+cont+` que coloquei no JavaScript.

Também não consigo retornar da foto 9 até a foto 1 que seria `cont = 1` e `cont +8`.

Comment: Não tenho certeza se é isso que precisa, mas dê uma olhada [nessa implementação](http://jsfiddle.net/1ao1Ljag/) onde eu agrupo imagens e seus respectivos *captions*.

Comment: Você pode [edit] a pergunta é incluir os [trechos relevantes do código](/help/mcve)? Sem isso não tem como respondermos.

Answer (score 0):

Para voltar para a primeira basta fazer (em javascript, se estou pensando correto):

```
cont++; // incrementa cont
if(cont == 9) {
    cont = 1;
};
```

Acredito que isso também resolva o problema do texto, pelo que estou entendendo.